# How to fix json error Expecting 'STRING', got '}'

Tags: c#, json

This is my string that I believe to be json output. I am getting

> Expecting 'STRING', got '}'.

Can anyone help me to resolve this please?

```
{
    "shipToAddress": {
    "type": "ST",
    "recordId": "ST",
    "locationNumber": "",
    "companyName1": "",
    "companyName2": "",
    "address1": "",
    "address2": "",
    "address3": "",
    "address4": "",
    "city": "",
    "state": "",
    "postalCode": "",
    "country": "",
    "dunsNumber": "",
    "dunsType": "",
    "contactPhone": "",
    "contactEmail": "",
    "contactFax": "",
    "contactOther": "",
    "locationCode": "",
    "consolidator": ""
    },
    "shipFromAddress": {
    "type": "ST",
    "recordId": "ST",
    "locationNumber": "",
    "companyName1": "",
    "companyName2": "",
    "address1": "",
    "address2": "",
    "address3": "",
    "address4": "",
    "city": "",
    "state": "",
    "postalCode": "",
    "country": "",
    "dunsNumber": "",
    "dunsType": "",
    "contactPhone": "",
    "contactEmail": "",
    "contactFax": "",
    "contactOther": "",
    "locationCode": "",
    "consolidator": ""
    },
    "addresses": [
    {
      "type": "ST",
      "recordId": "ST",
      "locationNumber": "",
      "companyName1": "",
      "companyName2": "",
      "address1": "",
      "address2": "",
      "address3": "",
      "address4": "",
      "city": "",
      "state": "",
      "postalCode": "",
      "country": "",
      "dunsNumber": "",
      "dunsType": "",
      "contactPhone": "",
      "contactEmail": "",
      "contactFax": "",
      "contactOther": "",
      "locationCode": "",
      "consolidator": ""
    }
    ],
    "orders": [
    {
      "recordId": "3",
      "poNumber": "0006630041",
      "items": [
        {
          "itemComponents": [
            {
              "itemNotes": [
                {
                  "recordId": "",
                  "type": "",
                  "note": ""
                }
              ],
              "recordId": "3",
              "lineNo": "3",
              "sublineNo": "3",
              "originalLineNo": "3",
              "qty": 0,
              "unitMeasure": "EA",
              "upcCode": "",
              "vendorNumber": "",
              "unitSize": "42",
              "itemColor": "BLK/RED",
              "customerItem": "",
              "gtinNumber": "",
              "upcCaseCode": "",
              "prepackCode": "",
              "caseGroupCode": "",
              "skuNumber": "",
              "unitPrice": "405.46",
              "priceBasis": "",
              "sellingPrice": 995,
              "discountPercent": 0,
              "shipDate": 060419,
              "packSize": 1,
              "inners": 1,
              "itemDesc": "",
              "itemWeight": "",
              "itemReferenceId": 0,
              "lotNumber": "",
              "nrfSize": "",
              "nrfColor": "",
              "nrfDesc": "",
              "unitSizeBuyer": "",
              "itemColorBuyer": "",
              "buyerStyleNo": "",
              "countryOfOrigin": "",
              "ticketType": "",
              "mfgName": "",
              "mfgCity": "",
              "mfgCountry": ""
            }
          ],
          "recordId": "",
          "lineNo": "",
          "sublineNo": "",
          "originalLineNo": "",
          "qty": 0,
          "unitMeasure": "EA",
          "upcCode": "",
          "vendorNumber": "",
          "unitSize": "",
          "itemColor": "",
          "customerItem": "",
          "gtinNumber": "",
          "upcCaseCode": "",
          "prepackCode": "",
          "caseGroupCode": "",
          "skuNumber": "",
          "unitPrice": "",
          "priceBasis": "",
          "sellingPrice": 0,
          "discountPercent": 0,
          "shipDate": 0,
          "packSize": 0,
          "inners": 0,
          "itemDesc": "",
          "itemWeight": "",
          "itemReferenceId": 0,
          "lotNumber": "",
          "nrfSize": "",
          "nrfColor": "",
          "nrfDesc": "",
          "unitSizeBuyer": "",
          "itemColorBuyer": "",
          "buyerStyleNo": "",
          "countryOfOrigin": "",
          "ticketType": "",
          "mfgName": "",
          "mfgCity": "",
          "mfgCountry": "",
          "extItemRef": "",
          "custFld01Nam": "",
          "custFld01Val": "",
          "custFld02Nam": "",
          "custFld02Val": "",
          "custFld03Nam": "",
          "custFld03Val": "",
          "qtyShip": 0,
          "qtyRemain": 0,
          "itemPackCode": "",
          "itemDimensionLength": 0,
          "itemDimensionWidth": 0,
          "itemDimensionHeight": 0,
          "itemDimensionUom": "",
          "cartonLenght": 0,
          "cartonWidth": 0,
          "cartonHeight": 0,
          "cartonUom": "",
          "itemStatus": "AC",
          "statusReason": "backorder_cancel",
          "statusDesc": "",
          "qtyBackorder": 0,
          "backorderDate": 0
        },
        {
          "recordId": "4",
          "poNumber": "0006630041",
          "items": [
            {
              "itemComponents": [
                {
                  "itemNotes": [
                    {
                      "recordId": "",
                      "type": "",
                      "note": ""
                    }
                  ],
                  "recordId": "4",
                  "lineNo": "4",
                  "sublineNo": "4",
                  "originalLineNo": "4",
                  "qty": 0,
                  "unitMeasure": "EA",
                  "upcCode": "",
                  "vendorNumber": "",
                  "unitSize": "43",
                  "itemColor": "BLK/RED",
                  "customerItem": "",
                  "gtinNumber": "",
                  "upcCaseCode": "",
                  "prepackCode": "",
                  "caseGroupCode": "",
                  "skuNumber": "",
                  "unitPrice": "405.46",
                  "priceBasis": "",
                  "sellingPrice": 995,
                  "discountPercent": 0,
                  "shipDate": 060419,
                  "packSize": 1,
                  "inners": 1,
                  "itemDesc": "",
                  "itemWeight": "",
                  "itemReferenceId": 0,
                  "lotNumber": "",
                  "nrfSize": "",
                  "nrfColor": "",
                  "nrfDesc": "",
                  "unitSizeBuyer": "",
                  "itemColorBuyer": "",
                  "buyerStyleNo": "",
                  "countryOfOrigin": "",
                  "ticketType": "",
                  "mfgName": "",
                  "mfgCity": "",
                  "mfgCountry": ""
                }
              ],
              "recordId": "",
              "lineNo": "",
              "sublineNo": "",
              "originalLineNo": "",
              "qty": 0,
              "unitMeasure": "EA",
              "upcCode": "",
              "vendorNumber": "",
              "unitSize": "",
              "itemColor": "",
              "customerItem": "",
              "gtinNumber": "",
              "upcCaseCode": "",
              "prepackCode": "",
              "caseGroupCode": "",
              "skuNumber": "",
              "unitPrice": "",
              "priceBasis": "",
              "sellingPrice": 0,
              "discountPercent": 0,
              "shipDate": 0,
              "packSize": 0,
              "inners": 0,
              "itemDesc": "",
              "itemWeight": "",
              "itemReferenceId": 0,
              "lotNumber": "",
              "nrfSize": "",
              "nrfColor": "",
              "nrfDesc": "",
              "unitSizeBuyer": "",
              "itemColorBuyer": "",
              "buyerStyleNo": "",
              "countryOfOrigin": "",
              "ticketType": "",
              "mfgName": "",
              "mfgCity": "",
              "mfgCountry": "",
              "extItemRef": "",
              "custFld01Nam": "",
              "custFld01Val": "",
              "custFld02Nam": "",
              "custFld02Val": "",
              "custFld03Nam": "",
              "custFld03Val": "",
              "qtyShip": 0,
              "qtyRemain": 0,
              "itemPackCode": "",
              "itemDimensionLength": 0,
              "itemDimensionWidth": 0,
              "itemDimensionHeight": 0,
              "itemDimensionUom": "",
              "cartonLenght": 0,
              "cartonWidth": 0,
              "cartonHeight": 0,
              "cartonUom": "",
              "itemStatus": "AC",
              "statusReason": "backorder_cancel",
              "statusDesc": "",
              "qtyBackorder": 0,
              "backorderDate": 0
            },
            {
              "recordId": "5",
              "poNumber": "0006630041",
              "items": [
                {
                  "itemComponents": [
                    {
                      "itemNotes": [
                        {
                          "recordId": "",
                          "type": "",
                          "note": ""
                        }
                      ],
                      "recordId": "5",
                      "lineNo": "5",
                      "sublineNo": "5",
                      "originalLineNo": "5",
                      "qty": 0,
                      "unitMeasure": "EA",
                      "upcCode": "",
                      "vendorNumber": "",
                      "unitSize": "44",
                      "itemColor": "BLK/RED",
                      "customerItem": "",
                      "gtinNumber": "",
                      "upcCaseCode": "",
                      "prepackCode": "",
                      "caseGroupCode": "",
                      "skuNumber": "",
                      "unitPrice": "405.46",
                      "priceBasis": "",
                      "sellingPrice": 995,
                      "discountPercent": 0,
                      "shipDate": 060419,
                      "packSize": 1,
                      "inners": 1,
                      "itemDesc": "",
                      "itemWeight": "",
                      "itemReferenceId": 0,
                      "lotNumber": "",
                      "nrfSize": "",
                      "nrfColor": "",
                      "nrfDesc": "",
                      "unitSizeBuyer": "",
                      "itemColorBuyer": "",
                      "buyerStyleNo": "",
                      "countryOfOrigin": "",
                      "ticketType": "",
                      "mfgName": "",
                      "mfgCity": "",
                      "mfgCountry": ""
                    }
                  ],
                  "recordId": "",
                  "lineNo": "",
                  "sublineNo": "",
                  "originalLineNo": "",
                  "qty": 0,
                  "unitMeasure": "EA",
                  "upcCode": "",
                  "vendorNumber": "",
                  "unitSize": "",
                  "itemColor": "",
                  "customerItem": "",
                  "gtinNumber": "",
                  "upcCaseCode": "",
                  "prepackCode": "",
                  "caseGroupCode": "",
                  "skuNumber": "",
                  "unitPrice": "",
                  "priceBasis": "",
                  "sellingPrice": 0,
                  "discountPercent": 0,
                  "shipDate": 0,
                  "packSize": 0,
                  "inners": 0,
                  "itemDesc": "",
                  "itemWeight": "",
                  "itemReferenceId": 0,
                  "lotNumber": "",
                  "nrfSize": "",
                  "nrfColor": "",
                  "nrfDesc": "",
                  "unitSizeBuyer": "",
                  "itemColorBuyer": "",
                  "buyerStyleNo": "",
                  "countryOfOrigin": "",
                  "ticketType": "",
                  "mfgName": "",
                  "mfgCity": "",
                  "mfgCountry": "",
                  "extItemRef": "",
                  "custFld01Nam": "",
                  "custFld01Val": "",
                  "custFld02Nam": "",
                  "custFld02Val": "",
                  "custFld03Nam": "",
                  "custFld03Val": "",
                  "qtyShip": 0,
                  "qtyRemain": 0,
                  "itemPackCode": "",
                  "itemDimensionLength": 0,
                  "itemDimensionWidth": 0,
                  "itemDimensionHeight": 0,
                  "itemDimensionUom": "",
                  "cartonLenght": 0,
                  "cartonWidth": 0,
                  "cartonHeight": 0,
                  "cartonUom": "",
                  "itemStatus": "AC",
                  "statusReason": "backorder_cancel",
                  "statusDesc": "",
                  "qtyBackorder": 0,
                  "backorderDate": 0
                }
              ],
              "cartons": [
                {
                  "pack": [
                    {
                      "lineNo": 0,
                      "qtyPack": 0
                    }
                  ],
                  "recordId": "35210369",
                  "cartonCode": "",
                  "cartonQty": 0,
                  "palletId": 0,
                  "cartonWeight": 0,
                  "cartonLength": 0,
                  "cartonWidth": 0,
                  "cartonHeight": 0,
                  "cartonUom": "",
                  "cartonGroupCode": "",
                  "packSlipNumber": "",
                  "trackingNumber": ""
                }
              ],
              "billToAddress": {
                "type": "BT",
                "recordId": "BT",
                "locationNumber": "",
                "companyName1": "",
                "companyName2": "",
                "address1": "",
                "address2": "",
                "address3": "",
                "address4": "",
                "city": "",
                "state": "",
                "postalCode": "",
                "country": "",
                "dunsNumber": "",
                "dunsType": "",
                "contactPhone": "",
                "contactEmail": "",
                "contactFax": "",
                "contactOther": "",
                "locationCode": "",
                "consolidator": ""
              },
              "remitToAddress": {
                "type": "RE",
                "recordId": "RE",
                "locationNumber": "",
                "companyName1": "",
                "companyName2": "",
                "address1": "",
                "address2": "",
                "address3": "",
                "address4": "",
                "city": "",
                "state": "",
                "postalCode": "",
                "country": "",
                "dunsNumber": "",
                "dunsType": "",
                "contactPhone": "",
                "contactEmail": "",
                "contactFax": "",
                "contactOther": "",
                "locationCode": "",
                "consolidator": ""
              },
              "location": "0689",
              "shipToLocation": "",
              "releaseNumber": "",
              "contractNumber": "",
              "poType": "",
              "poCategory": "",
              "customerOrderNumber": "",
              "customerOrderRef": "",
              "promoteCode": "",
              "salesOrderNumber": "",
              "customerAccount": "",
              "buyerAccount": "",
              "buyerEmail": "",
              "vendor": "",
              "vendorNumberAp": "30",
              "poDate": 0,
              "requestedDeliveryDate": 0,
              "departmentNumber": "0149",
              "departmentDescription": "",
              "invoiceNumber": "SI19-000001",
              "invoiceDate": 20190528,
              "detailLineCount": 0,
              "orderCartons": 0,
              "orderWeight": 0,
              "orderVolume": 0
            }
          ],
          "pallets": [
            {
              "recordId": "",
              "palletId": 0,
              "palletCode": "",
              "palletType": "1",
              "cartonCount": 0,
              "palletWeight": 0,
              "totalWeight": 0,
              "weightUom": "",
              "palletLength": 0,
              "palletWidth": 0,
              "palletHeight": 0,
              "palletUom": "",
              "palletTiers": 0,
              "palletBlocks": 0,
              "packSize": 0,
              "inners": 0
            }
          ],
          "appointmentNumber": "",
          "billOfLading": "",
          "carrierCode": "",
          "carrierCustom": 0,
          "carrierService": "CX",
          "contactEmail": "",
          "contactFax": "",
          "contactName": "",
          "contactPhone": "",
          "containerCarrierCode": "",
          "containerType": "2B",
          "custWhsNumber": "",
          "deliveryDate": 20190528,
          "externalId": "",
          "fobCode": "CC",
          "fobLocation": "OR",
          "fobText": "",
          "importHandlingCode": "",
          "importLocCode": "",
          "importLocType": "",
          "importUnLocCode": "",
          "importVesselName": "",
          "importVoyageNumber": "",
          "masterBillOfLading": "",
          "packCodeContainer": "",
          "packCodeMaterial": "",
          "proNumber": "",
          "routingInstructions": "",
          "sealNumber": "",
          "shipDate": 20190528,
          "shipmentId": "SH19-000001",
          "shipMode": "",
          "shipTime": "",
          "tagId": 0,
          "trailerNumber": "",
          "transitTime": "",
          "transitTimeType": "",
          "transportTermsCode": "",
          "transportTermsQual": "",
          "vendor": "",
          "vendorNumberAp": "30"
        }
```

Comment: Copy and paste your JSON here: https://jsonlint.com/ and choose Validate JSON  which will allow you to find the problems.

Comment: What we need is the code that consumes this json... The one throwing the exception.  What library are you using etc.

Comment: Start with the following: don't prefix numbers with a zero: 060419 should be 60419 instead.

Comment: @Gixabel: Since it's a date it should be a string, `"060419"`.

Comment: Your json is not valid. It has many missing clossing brackets

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've posted 580 lines of JSON, with no indication of where you believe the problem to be, or what you've done to try to isolate it - that makes it much harder to help you than if you'd reduced it to as small an example as possible, ideally with the code you're using as well. I'd suggest reading https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for what makes a good question (in my opinion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the data, it looks like their are two problems.

1. Your collection of orders and items are not closed.
2. The main json object is not closed.

Let's start with the Order and Item collection:

[image: Order and Item Problem Area]

The item collection in the order with recordId 3 is not closed properly. This is resulting in the order with recordId 4 being a child of record 3's items. Additionally there is no closure to the order record itself (missing curly braces).

To fix this, place a square brace, then a curly brace, before the comma, at the end of the item properties.

[image: How to Fix Order]

Resulting in:

[image: Fixed Orders]

Now that we have the orders cleaned up, there are just a couple braces at the end of the file that need to be closed.

The order collection is missing its closing square brace, and the main json object is missing its closing curly brace:

[image: Missing Closing Braces]

Resulting in:

[image: Fixed Closing Braces]

So, this fixes the structural issues. As @Gixabel mentioned, you also need to enclose all the instances of shipDate as stings, since they are representations of dates.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got your idea and it has resolved.